# Continuous X variable used but still getting Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, nse

I am creating a function that uses a forloop to create and return a list of ggplots. When I try to view any of the returned plots, e.g. by calling `plots["aClass_20_30"]`, I get:

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

However, if I create one of the plots outside the forloop, as below, it shows up just fine because the variable in question, `myVar`, IS continuous:

```
tpp %>%
  filter(risk_class == "aClass", age_buckets=="20_30") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=myVar)) +
  geom_area(stat='bin') +
  labs(title = paste("aClass", "20_30", sep="_"))
```

This is the function:

```
plot_fixed_age_class_against <- function(variable) {

  temp <- tpp %>% 
    select_('age_buckets', 'rclass', variable) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(rclass))

  plots <- vector("list", 48)

  for (class in unique(temp$rclass)) {
    for (age in unique(temp$age_buckets)) {

      print(paste(class, age, sep="_"))

      plots[[paste(class, age, sep="_")]] <- 
        temp %>%
        filter(rclass == class, age_buckets==age) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=variable)) +
          geom_area(stat='bin') +
          labs(title = paste(class, age, sep="_"))
    }
  }
  #print(plots)

  return(plots)
}
```

and I call it using `plots <- plot_fixed_age_class_against("myVar")`

If I change bin to count within the forloop, the graphs show up but there is nothing plotted on them. However, using bin outside the forloop, as above, works perfectly. `myVar` is numeric.

Comment: Due to it's usage of [NSE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html) it's always tricky to use ggplot2 (and other popular packages) functions in custom functions. ggplot thinks you want the character string "myVar" as x-axis, which is of course discrete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aes_string` to get ggplot2 to play nice with string arguments:

```
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(var) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(var)) +
    geom_histogram()
}


f("cyl")
```

Raises this error:

```
Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?
```

But if we use `ggplot2`s alternative to NSE, `aes_string`:

```
f <- function(var) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(var)) +
    geom_histogram()
}


f("cyl")
```

The plot is drawn without error.

## Edit:

Thanks to @akrun for the reminder that `aes_string` etc are soft depreciated.

According to the [ggplot2 docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html#quasiquotation) is [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-expressions) one of the suggested `tidyverse` alternatives to `aes_string` :

But if we use `ggplot2`s alternative to NSE, `aes_string`:

```
  f <- function(var) {

    var <- enquo(var)

    ggplot(mtcars, aes(!!var)) +
      geom_histogram()
  }


  f(cyl)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of `tidyverse`, the `aes_string` would get deprecated.  Instead, we can use `rlang::sym` to convert to symbol and then evaluate

```
library(ggplot2)
f <- function(var) {
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(!! rlang::sym(var))) +
   geom_histogram()
     }


f("cyl")
```

---

Also, if we are passing either quoted or unquoted, one option is to use `ensym`

```
f <- function(var) {
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(!! rlang::ensym(var))) +
   geom_histogram()
     }

f("cyl")
f(cyl)
```